# Assigning User (Float values) Input Into Empty List Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, floating-point

This is an assigned project.  T"he program prompts the user to interactively enter eight batting averages, which the program stores in an array." The given batting averages are floats.  I am a newbie with Python and can't figure out how to add a "float" to an empty list.  My code is below with the error msg.

```
# Declare a named constant for array size here.
MAX_AVERAGES = 8

# Declare array here.
averages = []
averages1 = []



battingAverage=0
averageString=0

# Write a loop to get batting averages from user and assign to array.

for i in range(MAX_AVERAGES):
    averageString = input("Enter a batting average: ")
    battingAverage = float(averageString)
    MAX_AVERAGES - 1

# Assign value to array
number = battingAverage
    averages1.append(averages)
    averageString + 1
```

The result from above code:
Enter a batting average: .111
Enter a batting average: .222
Enter a batting average: .333
Enter a batting average: .444
Enter a batting average: .555
Enter a batting average: .666
Enter a batting average: .777
Enter a batting average: .888
[[]]

Not sure how I ended up with two nested empty list.

Comment: As is, your code would throw an `IndentationError`.  Can you update the last 3 lines of your code?  Either `number` is supposed to be indented, or the other 2 lines shouldn't be indented. (its hard to tell which you meant, although I can guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you're just trying to write,

```
# Declare a named constant for array size here.
MAX_AVERAGES = 3

# Declare array here.
averages = []

# Write a loop to get batting averages from user and assign to array.
for i in range(MAX_AVERAGES):
    averages.append(float(input("Enter a batting average: ")))

print(averages)
```

#### Output

```
Enter a batting average: 2
Enter a batting average: 1
Enter a batting average: 3
[2.0, 1.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: the assignment included the variable```battingAverage=float(averageString)```. I assumed I had to use it in coding but I guess "behind the scenes" input was converted to a float?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
MAX_AVERAGES = 8   
averages = []   

for i in range(MAX_AVERAGES):
    averageString = input("Enter a batting average: ")
    averages.append(float(averageString))
```

But I assume this is not what you want.  It is difficult to tell because you have syntax errors that would immediately break your code, also there seems to be a lot of unnecessary variables.

Comment: the assignment included the variable battingAverage=float(averageString) which threw me. I was not sure how to use it.

Comment: @NinaPy that makes sense in hindsight.  Often assignments ask you to do things in ways that are contrary to the *pythonic* approach, in order to learn a concept.  This can result in confusion like in this case.  Also, it threw me too, and I spent a lot of time trying to figure out if my answer was acceptable or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are obtaining a nested list because of this line: `averages1.append(averages)`. `averages1` is an empty list, to which you are adding an element. This element is `averages`, which is also an empty list.

Maybe what you are looking for is `averages1.append(number)`, which adds to the list the number the user entered.

Also note that the lines of code `MAX_AVERAGES - 1` and `averageString + 1` are not doing anything because the result is not being assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

## you can use append functions for list

```
    max_average=8
    averages=[]
    for i in range(max_average):
        battingAverage=float(input('Enter a batting average: '))
        averages.append(battingAverage)
    print(averages)
```